# Can i use fixed user specific PeerJs ID for each user while connecting for chat in WebRTC.

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

I am using webrtc for video call and chat. 
- Is there a way to create users in webrtc server with fixed ids. 
- Can i use a fixed chat id for each user while establishing chat connection.

Comment: what is your signalling mechanism ie  websockets , sipml5 , xmpp , etc ?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Nothing prevents you from letting the user choose their own ID. However, with peerjs there is no authentication when choosing your ID.

Thus, say you choose your ID as "my-fixed-id", you can always try and use this ID and tell your friends that this is you. Since there is no authentication, nothing stops someone else from choosing this ID for themselves. So someone can "steal" your ID.

Good news:
If you choose an ID that is hard to guess and ONLY tell your trusted friends, you could theoretically do what you want to do. Then you can keep a list of your friends in localStorage and try and connect to their ID's when you load the page and then maybe every minute or so.

Be careful. You cannot verify that the person claims he is who he says.